# Why can't I get std::function<std::vector<T>::iterator> to bind to lambda returning that type?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why this isn't working. I have a function that returns the result of the `std::find` method. I read that it returns an iterator to object it finds. But when I try passing the lambda that returns that value it gives me a bunch of errors, why?

```
void f(std::function<std::vector<int>::iterator()>) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3};

    auto p = [=] (int n) {
        return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), n);
    };

    f(p);
}
```

I get a lot of incomprehensible errors. I even did a type check here and it returned true:

```
std::is_same<std::vector<int>::iterator, decltype(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), N))>::value;
// -> true
```

So why doesn't this work when I pass a function to `f` with `std::function` that returns this type?

Comment: Can you provide a hint about what errors you got? Just the first one or two; after that they're usually nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `int` parameter missing in your `std::function` parameter was a copy-paste mistake, apparently `v.begin()` and `v.end()` return `const_iterator`s rather than normal iterators.

This is due to the fact that your lambda was capturing by value, making your `std::vector` `const`(and thus its iterators). Capturing everything by reference [works](http://ideone.com/Qrn9be), otherwise, your `std::function` should return a `const_iterator`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

void f(std::function<std::vector<int>::iterator (int)>) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3};

    auto p = [&] (int n) {
        return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), n);
    };

    f(p);
}
```

Comment: A lambda that is not declared mutable has a function call operator declared const. As a result names captured by copy are const inside the lambda body. Thus the possible solutions are: 1. capture by reference, 2. use const_iterator or 3. use a mutable lambda (if you really need mutating iterators, but don't want modify the original v)

Answer (score 2):

As you are capturing by value, the captured `vector` (and associated iterators) are `const` by default. If you want it to be mutable, you need to change the lambda:

```
auto p = [=] (int n) mutable {
    return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), n);
};
```

Comment: +1, didn't know capturing by value meant "the outside world is const".

Comment: @mfontanini: in fact it does mean more than that: it means even the copies of the captured values in the lambda closure are `const`. unless you make the lambda `mutable`, the generated call operator has the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

Because f expects a function that takes no arguments, but your lambda has one int parameter.

Comment: Still doesn't work with `std::function<std::vector<int>::iterator(int)>`

Comment: See answer from mfontanini (and my comment there)